# Recursive String to Tree Parser

Tags: java, string, algorithm, arraylist, tree

At the moment I am trying to implement a recursive solution to build a tree structure, I've split the String up so for example

```
input: "(3 + 5)" 
Output: [1, 3], [1, +], [1, 5]
input: "3 + 5"
Output [0, 3], [0, +], [0, 5]
```

This is to represent open bracketed expressions (the first output) 
and whole expressions (the second output). I'm a little bit confused (and sleep deprived) on how to call this recursively, so if the input was much larger, it would keep creating subtrees? Any ideas? Or links to documentation :)

```
public Node parseStringToTree(String str)
{
    str = str.replaceAll(" ", "");

    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ArrayList<Integer> depths = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int openCount = 0;
    int openClose = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == '(') {
            openCount++;
        } else if (c == ')') {
            openClose++;
        } else {
            int currentDepth = openCount - openClose;
            chars.add(c);
            depths.add(currentDepth);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
        int depth = depths.get(i);
        char c = chars.get(i);

        System.out.println("[" + depth + ", " + c + "]");
    }

    return root;
}
```

Comment: how do you get those 1s in your output?

Comment: Looking at the code that looks like the nesting depth.

Comment: By keeping a track of the opened brackets - where this statement  int currentDepth = openCount - openClose; should equal 0 if it is in a current 'balanced' state. If there is a closing bracket found without opening it should return -1 or throw an error or something, but im not at that stage yet.

Comment: If you're writing recursive code, it often helps if you imagine you're right in the middle of the string and your recursive method is called: what information do you need and what information do you need to return to the caller? In this case as a minimum, the functions needs the current position in the string (probably right after an opening parenthesis) and the current depth. And it needs to return the subtree it produces and the string position it finished its job (after the matching closing parenthesis). Or if it can't find one, it should throw an exception.

Comment: Then proceed to create a skeleton implementation: determine what format you want to represent the tree in (it will probably be a recursive structure, although it can be as simple as a list). Then proceed to the recursive parser ignoring every character that isn't `(` or `)`. As the last step you can add the "body" of your recursive method, which parses everything else until it bumps into an opening or closing parenthesis.

Comment: I don't see how anything presented implements a *tree*, and if the given method does anything at all to `Node`s' instance variables then I am missing it.  Before you can move ahead, you need to get a firm grasp of what a node in your tree represents.

Comment: A common way to structure an expression tree is that each node represents either a literal value or the result of an operation.  You can consider `(`, `)` pairs to perform an identity operation, if you wish, so as to represent them in the tree, but the parentheses don't necessarily need to be explicitly represented at all.

Comment: Node left, right; Object value; are the instance variables, and your right it doesn't do anything with them yet. I'm still working that out, but I believe that's all I need at the moment?